# Grails RESTful Controller. POST hits index() instead of save()

Tags: json, rest, grails

I'm trying to create a RESTful controller in Grails 2.3.4.  I am following the documentation exactly, however, any time I try to POST, I always hit the index method.  The only way I can get save() to work is to delete the index method.  This doesn't make any sense to me.

I have tried both extending the RestfulController superclass: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/webServices.html#extendingRestfulController

And implementing my own methods: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/webServices.html#restControllersStepByStep

And yet, when I post to my url, it only hits the index method, whether it's the one in the RestfulController I'm extending, or in my own method.

I have `"/api/lab"(controller: "lab")` in UrlMappings.groovy
I have `json: ['application/json', 'text/json'],` defined in my mime types

I've tried adding and removing `static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]` from my controller.

But no matter what I do, I cannot seem to hit save().

This is my controller when I am implementing my own controller:

```
class LabController {
static responseFormats = ['json']

def userService

def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    Patient patient = userService.currentUser.patient
    render PatientLab.findAllByPatientAndType(patient, LabType.findByName(LabType.LAB_TYPE_INR)) as JSON
}

@Transactional
def save() {
    Patient patient = userService.currentUser.patient
    LabType inrType = LabType.findByName(LabType.LAB_TYPE_INR)

    boolean labAlreadyExists = PatientLab.findByPatientAndLabDateAndType(patient, request.JSON.labDate, inrType)

    if (labAlreadyExists) {
        render {result: "Lab already exists"} as JSON
        return
    }

    PatientLab patientLab = new PatientLab()
    patientLab.patient = patient
    patientLab.origin = LabOrigin.MOBILE_APP
    patientLab.type = inrType
    patientLab.result = request.JSON.result
    patientLab.measurement = UnitType.findByUnit(UnitType.UNIT_TYPE_NONE)
    patientLab.labDate = new Date()

}
}
```

This is my controller when extending RestfulController:

```
class LabController extends RestfulController {
static responseFormats = ['json']

LabController() {
    super(PatientLab)
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the allowedMethods is just going to stop you from getting a GET request to save(), what you really want is the [Restful Mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#restfulMappings) so instead of mapping with

```
"/api/lab"(controller: "lab")
```

Use

```
"/api/labs"(resources: "lab")
```

That will map your POST to /api/labs to the `save()` method. If you don't want to use plurals in your rest controller you can use `resource` instead but I most of the time go with plurals. I like to have a list of which methods I am supporting and I do that with `includes:['index', 'show']` allowing me to easily support just a few operations.

Comment: Haha, wow, you are so right, I can't believe I screwed that up.  I guess I lied when I said I followed the documentation exactly :/
Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @RobLouie Glad it helped, I've missed that setting myself a few times.